# Device Token not saving

Tags: swift, notifications

Okay so when a user pushes a button in the app intro, it lets them register for notifications. Once this is done, I'm trying to save the token to send to my sever and its coming up as blank:

This is the code in my intro.

```
let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)


var myDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
                var tokenString: String = myDelegate.tokenString1

                tokenString = tokenString.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "<>"))
                tokenString = tokenString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(tokenString, forKey: "notification")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

This is the code in my app delegate:

```
    var tokenString1 = ""
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        var tokenString: String = deviceToken.description
        tokenString = tokenString.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "<>"))
        var tokenString1 = tokenString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(tokenString1, forKey: "notification")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

    }
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
        print("Failed to register:", error)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **local** variable `tokenString1` in `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` and the **instance** variable `tokenString1` are completely different objects. The local variable is preferred and the instance variable is never set.

Solution: remove the keyword `var` in `didRegister ...`

```
tokenString1 = tokenString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
```

There is no need at all to save the token in user defaults. You get always the actual one in the register method, the method is invoked every time the app launches.